# How do I use the value in radiobutton in the main code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am basically trying to get the x variable outside of the function or make a variable that changes based on the radiobuttons.

```
x = ''

def test():
global x
x = y.get()

y = tk.StringVar()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Pizza", variable = y, value = 'pz',padx=10, pady=10,command=test)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text = "Burger", variable = y, value = 'bk',padx=10, pady=10,command=test)

print (x)
```

Thanks for any help I am new to python and tkinter concepts.

Comment: Why do you want it outside the function?

Comment: I would like it outside the function in order to use the value and store it in another variable to be able to use it as IF/ELSE statement in a later part of the code that uses 3 different sets of radio buttons.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? Kindly explain

Comment: I would basically like to make it so when I click the radiobutton it stores the value as a variable that I can use in a later part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap it in a `class` and add the variable to `self`, then any class member can access it. In the case you need to pass additional variables from a local scope, you will need to use a `lambda`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def print_value(self):
        print(self.radio_svar.get())

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.radio_svar = tk.StringVar(value='pz')

        self.radio_a = tk.Radiobutton(
            self, text="Pizza",
            variable=self.radio_svar, value='pz',
            padx=10, pady=10, command=self.print_value
        )
        self.radio_a.pack()

        self.radio_b = tk.Radiobutton(
            self, text="Burger",
            variable=self.radio_svar, value='bk',
            padx=10, pady=10, command=self.print_value
        )
        self.radio_b.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```